# If a key has a value then print the value ruby

Tags: json, ruby, hash, key

I'm trying to only put value of the key `self` only if the key `escalation_policies` has a value. This is an example a schedule that doesn't have an escalation policy hence I don't want the value for the key `self`

```
{"schedules"=>
  [{"id"=>"0000000",
    "type"=>"schedule",
    "summary"=>"-PROD-",
    "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/",
    "html_url"=>"https://pagerduty.com/schedules/",
    "name"=>"-PROD-",
    "time_zone"=>"America/",
    "description"=>nil,
    "privilege"=>nil,
    "users"=>
     [{"id"=>"0000000",
       "type"=>"user_reference",
       "summary"=>"DOo Kkkk",
       "self"=>"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/",
       "html_url"=>"https://target.pagerduty.com/users/"}],
    "escalation_policies"=>[],
    "teams"=>[]},
}
```

My code to conquer this challenge is:

```
somefile = File.open("Schedule_Api.txt", "a+")
  jdoc.fetch("schedules").each do |schedule|
    somefile.puts schedule["self"] if schedule["escalation_policies"].exists? == true 
  end
somefile.close
```

This variable `jdoc` is the curl for the website. And this is the result I get from this is `undefined method`exists?' for []:Array (NoMethodError)`. Is there another alternative to this then the method`exists?`. Any help will be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I suggest rewording "only if the key escalation_policies has a value". Although on the higher nontechnical level an empty array represents the absence of a value, this could be confusing to others as it was to me. Better to say "only if the hash's value for the key escalation_policies is an array that is not empty" (or whose size > 0).

Comment: Will do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`.exists?` is a method from ActiveRecord, not on Array.

If you want to test for empty arrays, you probably want to do

```
somefile.puts schedule["self"] unless schedule["escalation_policies"].empty?
```

If you want to test for any value at all, just doing

```
somefile.puts schedule["self"] if schedule["escalation_policies"]
```

should work

Comment: Amazing! You were right! I see why my code was incorrect, but it pleases me that at least I was close! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  if schedule.has_key?("escalation_policies")
```

You could also test:

```
  if schedule["escalation_policies"]
```

which would return false not only if the key does not exist, but also if it does exist, and its corresponding value is nil.

If the absence of values will always be represented by an empty array (`[]`), then instead you can use `schedule["escalation_policies"].empty?` as mentioned by Rick Sullivan in his answer, or `schedule["escalation_policies"].any?` to test for an array size > 0.

Comment: Thank you! You were right as well, it seems I still have lots to learn.